# Website block on a time schedule

Tags: productivity

I would like to find a way to block the access to some websites from all the browsers of my laptop, but not just as Self-Control does for MacOS. I want to make kind of a time schedule, for example blocking Facebook between 8am and 8pm, and let it free outside this "window", and do the same with different "time-windows" for other websites... Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Google Chrome, you can use [StayFocusd](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stayfocusd/laankejkbhbdhmipfmgcngdelahlfoji/details?hl=en):

[image]